# Photoshop, script to find a layer that contains a word in its layer's name

Tags: javascript, photoshop

hope you guys can help me.
I need a script that can find a layers name, for example if i have this layers:

- `Wood 123 Canvas`
- `Wood 456 Specular`
- `Wood 789 Lights`

And i would like to find the layer that contains Canvas. And maybe, if its possible, change the layer's name color to green.

I found also this code i tried:

```
try {
(ref1 = new ActionReference()).putName(stringIDToTypeID('layer'),"Canvas"); // replace Canvas with your layer name
(desc1 = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(stringIDToTypeID('null'), ref1)
executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('select'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
} catch (e) {
    alert("Sorry, this layername does not exists");
}
```

This works great but only if the layer's name is exactly "Canvas".. and that's the problem

Comment: What Photoshop version?

Comment: CC2021, I noticed in this version works very well all scripts from previous versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Adobe [Javascript Scripting Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-javascript-ref-2020.pdf#G4.436296).

Looks like there is no faster way than to search for the right layers by hand:

```js
var layers = app.activeDocument.artLayers
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  if (/Canvas/.test(layers[i].name)) {
    // layers[i] name contains "Canvas"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Other scripting documentation can be found here: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html

Comment: Something like this? `var layers = app.activeDocument.artLayers
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  if (/Canvas/.test(layers[i].name)) {
    // layers[i] name contains "Canvas"
try {
(ref1 = new ActionReference()).putName(stringIDToTypeID('layer'), str.search(layers[i]));
(desc1 = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(stringIDToTypeID('null'), ref1)
executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('select'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
} catch (e) {
    alert("Sorry, this layername does not exists");
}

  } 
}
`

Comment: @JhosepNoa Em… `(ref1 = new ActionReference()).putName(stringIDToTypeID('layer'), layers[i].name);` for `ref1` I think…

Comment: `var layers = app.activeDocument.artLayers
for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
  if (/Canvas/.test(layers[i].name)) {
    // layers[i] name contains "Canvas"
try {
(ref1 = new ActionReference()).putName(stringIDToTypeID('layer'), layers[i].name);
(desc1 = new ActionDescriptor()).putReference(stringIDToTypeID('null'), ref1)
executeAction(stringIDToTypeID('select'), desc1, DialogModes.NO);
} catch (e) {
    alert("Sorry, this layername does not exists");
}

  } 
}

`